# Use PHP 5.6 for a site under Control Web Panel Pro rather than the global PHP 7.3

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 7.3 on a CWP Pro installation.
Most of the domains are fine with 7.3 but on one I'm using PHP 5.6 installed with PHP selector V2.
.htaccess: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php`

The CMS I'm using has a WebsocketChatServer which is turned on with a `shell_exec` PHP command.
The problem is that the chat server runs with PHP 7.3.

The shell_exec command looks something like `/path/Server.php start 14000 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $! > /path/process_id.txt`.
I tried changing `php` to `/opt/alt/php56` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/opt/alt/php56/bin/php` instead of `php` in CLI.
Took me a while to find the real path.